# TreeSet Duplicates

Tags: java, collections, set, treeset

I was trying to understand someones code.

```
public class Card  {
    String symbol;
    int no;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }
    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return symbol+" "+no;
    }

}
class MyComparator1 implements Comparator<Card> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Card arg0, Card arg1) {

        return arg0.getSymbol().compareTo(arg1.getSymbol());
    }

}

public class Card2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Card c2;        
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<Card> c = new TreeSet<Card>(new MyComparator1());
    while(c.size()<4) {
        System.out.println("Enter symbol and number");
        String symbol = s.next();
        int no = s.nextInt();
        c2 = new Card();
        c2.setSymbol(symbol);
        c2.setNo(no);
        c.add(c2);
    }
    Iterator<Card> it = c.iterator();
    {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Card c1 = it.next();
            System.out.println(c1.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this we are trying to display the different colour with respective number
until we get 4 different color.

we are using treeset here. Example if we enter this input

```
a 1
b 2
c 2
b 4
d 2
```

output is

```
a 1
b 2
c 2
d 2
```

in this how Set recognize difference between b 2 & b 4?
if we take map and use symbol as key then it is under standable but how set found similarity we are just passing Card object?

Comment: Your comparator is only looking at the symbol value. Why are you surprised? Also, how did `d 2` turn into `d 4`?

Comment: thanks for finding mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyComparator1` instance you pass to the `TreeSet`'s constructor determines which objects are considered to be unique. In your example, it's the `symbol` property that determines uniqueness.

It would make more sense though to use both `symbol` and `no` to determine uniqueness, since two cards having the same symbol but different number shouldn't be considered identical (for example `b 2` & `b 4` should not be considered identical).

Comment: Ok comparator finds the uniqeness. Is this same when we implements the comparable??

Comment: @AyushGoyal It is similar. You can either use natural ordering (Comparable) or custom ordering (Comparator) when creating a TreeSet.